# Joomla add/edit article and section screens blank

Tags: php, joomla

I'm using Joomla v1.5.26 and for whatever reason when I navigate to [MYSITE.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&task=add](http://MYSITE.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&task=add) or if I try to edit any already existing articles (or sections) I get a screen with an empty body tag.

The other pages in the administrator part seem to be working.

It seems to be the same (or very similar) problem as this: http://www.justanswer.com/computer-programming/32fo1-when-hit-new-button-article-manager-joomla.html but this is the only instance I could find of the problem, and it isn't resolved at the end of the article.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This can happen when the PHP memory limit is too low. http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-dec-2010/item/295-Are-you-getting-your-fair-share-of-PHP-memory

Comment: I don't see anything in my logs folder that's newer than october. I checked my php memory limit, and it said it was 64 MB.

Comment: Just ran the memory tester, and it allows full memory to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion:

1- Try to disable the editor you are using (Set it to no editor on global settings or on the user you are trying to edit with)

2- Try to reupload `components/com_content` from Joomla 1.5.26 source to your website and overwrite the existing file. There might be something missing.

Comment: I disabled the WYSIWYG Editor and it popped up! thanks so much!

Comment: Prefect, now you just have to use a different editor like JCE or  reupload the original editor